# How to steal eth using delegatecall and selfdestruct

Tags: contract-design, security

This [documentation](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction-to-smart-contracts.html#self-destruct) says

> Even if a contract’s code does not contain a call to selfdestruct, it can still perform that operation using delegatecall or callcode.

This worries me.

I've created some pseudo code to give a gist of a possible exploit.  The code below creates an "exception: invalid opcode", but you'll be able to follow my logic.  Assuming this style of attack works, what can be done to guard against it?

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2;        
contract Steal{
      function delegatecall_selfdestruct(address _target) external returns (bool _ans) {
          _ans = _target.delegatecall(bytes4(sha3("selfdestruct(address)")), this); 
      }
}

contract Mark { 
  function Deposit() payable {
  }
}
```

The idea is to send some testnet ETH to the contract Mark then use the Steal contract to call Mark and make it selfdestruct and give the ETH to the Steal Contract.

Comment: There's a difference between built-in solidity functions and publicly accessable contract functions. Your attack will not work

Comment: @TjadenHess besides, are there any token listed on an exchange actually using DELEGATECALL or CALLCODE ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It doesn't work to just call built-in Solidity functions in other contracts using delegatecall.

What delegatecall really does is call a function in another contract, which executes in the context of the first contract. It's really dangerous to make delegatecalls to contracts you don't trust. The documentation is warning you about this possibility:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2;        
contract Steal{
    address owner;
    function Steal() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }
    function innocence() {
        selfdestruct(owner);
    }
}

contract Mark { 
    function Deposit() payable {}
    function call(address a) {
        a.delegatecall(bytes4(sha3("innocence()"))); 
    }
}
```

If Mark calls Steal, then Mark will selfdestruct.

Comment: This example helps a lot, but when I test this, Mark calls steal and self destructs, but the ETH that was in Mark gets sent to address 0x0 even though address owner != 0x0.   

Can you help me understand why, and how a non zero address can be specified?  Thanks.

Comment: I think it must be because owner doesn't exist in Mark, and delegatecall uses Mark's environment, not Steal's. It might be interesting to add an "owner" variable to Mark and see if that gets the ETH.

Comment: @DennisPeterson I can add that `Steal` can even overwrite `Mark` bytecode (the bytecode stored at the address of Mark) through a Callcode to address 0 (this will create a contract not as the usual new address but at the address of `Mark`), because unlike `CALL` CodeAddr is not null. The bytecode which will be stored over `Mark` is `Steal`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working and up-to-date example:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.2;        
contract Steal{
    fallback() external {
        selfdestruct(payable(address(this)));
    }
}

contract Mark { 
    function callSteal(address _c) public {
        (bool success, ) = _c.delegatecall(""); 
        require(success, "something went wrong");
    }
}
```

When you call `callSteal` the Mark contract will be "selfdestructed".

Comment: The code is correct too!