# Removing / Unlisting Smart Contract from Etherscan.io

Tags: etherscan, abi

I've been creating several smart contracts for testing purpose, with the same Name, Symbol, Supply, & etc. And I'd like to remove/unlisting those smart contracts from etherscan because it is spammed the etherscan.io

EDIT:
All of those dummy smart contracts has been created and didn't implemented with delegatecall or callcode

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to delete a smart contract if selfdestruct() not implemented in it?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/39762/is-it-possible-to-delete-a-smart-contract-if-selfdestruct-not-implemented-in-i)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to steal eth using delegatecall and selfdestruct](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15087/how-to-steal-eth-using-delegatecall-and-selfdestruct)

Comment: I still didn't understand, based on the example code, they had `function call(address a) { a.delegatecall....`. So the first contract (innocent) must contain that line or not?